# Counting how many times a string appears within results

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query that pulls data from a number of tables. One of the fields is a customer_id which can appear within the results numerous times. Is there a way that I can append a field to my results showing the number of times each unique customer_id appears within the results set? My query as it stands is as follows...

```
SELECT customer.customer_id, customer.name, customer.email, Date_format(orders.datetime,'%d-%m-%Y') AS order_date, order_items.order_item_id, order_items.order_id

FROM order_items, product, orders, customer

WHERE order_items.product_id = product.product_id AND product.manufacturer = 'Nike' AND order_items.order_id = orders.order_id AND  orders.customer_id = customer.customer_id  ORDER BY customer_id, order_date
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add: in your SELECT -> `COUNT(customer.customer_id)`

And add the end of the query -> `GROUP BY (customer.customer_id)`

You may need to tweak the query somewhat - or break certain `SELECT` terms into subqueries for this to work.

Comment: Simple and effective. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Its inefficient but it should do the job:

```
SELECT 
    customer.customer_id, 
    customer.name, 
    customer.email, Date_format(orders.datetime,'%d-%m-%Y') AS order_date, 
    order_items.order_item_id, 
    order_items.order_id,
    tmp.za_count
FROM 
    order_items, product, orders, customer
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        customer.customer_id, 
        COUNT(*) as za_count

    FROM 
        order_items, product, orders, customer
    WHERE 
        order_items.product_id = product.product_id 
        AND product.manufacturer = 'Nike' 
        AND order_items.order_id = orders.order_id 
        AND  orders.customer_id = customer.customer_id 
    GROUP BY
        customer.customer_id
) as tmp
    ON tmp.customer_id = customer.customer_id
WHERE 
    order_items.product_id = product.product_id 
    AND product.manufacturer = 'Nike' 
    AND order_items.order_id = orders.order_id 
    AND  orders.customer_id = customer.customer_id  
ORDER BY 
    customer_id, 
    order_date
```